# Is there a way to split columns in R with and impute implied Values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to split a column in a data set that has codes separated by "-".  This creates two issues.  First i have to split the columns, but I also want to impute the values implied by the "-".  I was able to split the data using:

```
separate_rows(df, code, sep = "-")
```

but I still haven't found a way to impute the implied values.

```
name <- c('group1', 'group1','group1','group2', 'group1', 'group1', 
'group1')
code <- c('93790', '98960 - 98962', '98966 - 98969', '99078', 'S5950', 
'99241 - 99245', '99247')
df <- data.frame( name, code)
```

what I am trying to output would look something like:

```
group1 93790, 98960, 98961, 98962, 98966, 98967, 98968, 98969, S5950, 99241, 
99242, 99243, 99244, 99245, 99247
group2 99078
```

in this example, 98961, 98967 and 98968 are imputed and implied from the "-".

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: `98966-98969` isin the update

Comment: Here is what I get for the first row `group1 93790, 98960, 98961, 98962, 98966, 98967, 98968, 98969, S5950, 99241, 99242, 99243, 99244, 99245, 99247`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After we split the 'code', one option it to loop through the split elements with `map`, get a sequence (`:`), `unnest` and do a group_by `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(code = map(strsplit(as.character(code), " - "), ~  {
      x <- as.numeric(.x)
      if(length(x) > 1)  x[1]:x[2] else x})) %>%
  unnest(code) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(code = str_c(code, collapse=", "))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   name   code                                                  
#   <fct>  <chr>                                                  
# 1 group1 93790, 98960, 98961, 98962, 98966, 98967, 98968, 98969
# 2 group2 99078
```

---

Or another option is before the `separate_rows`, create a row index and use that for grouping by when we do a `complete`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    separate_rows(code, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(rn, name) %>%
    complete(code = min(code):max(code)) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(code = str_c(code, collapse =", "))
```

---

#### Update

If there are non-numeric elements

```
df %>% 
 mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
 separate_rows(code, convert = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(name, rn) %>% 
 complete(code = if(any(str_detect(code, '\\D'))) code else 
     as.character(min(as.numeric(code)):max(as.numeric(code)))) %>% 
 group_by(name) %>%
 summarise(code = str_c(code, collapse =", "))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  name   code                                                                                                   
#  <fct>  <chr>                                                                                                  
#1 group1 93790, 98960, 98961, 98962, 98966, 98967, 98968, 98969, S5950, 99241, 99242, 99243, 99244, 99245, 99247
#2 group2 99078
```

Comment: That is beautiful!  Works as expected.Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: when I apply this code to my real data set it get the following error.  Any idea what may be causing it?  I dont see any missing values  Is there a way to handle the NAs as exception?       [ Error in x[1]:x[2] : NA/NaN argument ]

Comment: @Brad_J  Can you try the second solution with `separate_rows` and check if it gives the error

Comment: Thanks.  I still get NA error.   [ Error in min(code):max(code) : NA/NaN argument ]

Comment: @Brad_J Perhaps you have some `NA` elements in 'code'  Can you check `df %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    separate_rows(code, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(rn, name)  %>% summarise(code = sum(is.na(code)))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun I just inspected all of the values in 'code' and no NA's or no blank values.  There are some that start with an alpha character.  Could that cause a problem?  I have updated the question adding an example of this

Comment: @Brad_J Yes, that would be the case, when it is converted to numeric with `as.numeric` or `convert = TRUE`, it gets converted to `NA`

Comment: @Brad_J I would remove the alpha part, `df %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number(), code = str_remove(code, "^[A-Za-z]"))`

Comment: that sort of works.  The only issue with this is it doesnt have the min/max so it is imputing values it shouldnt.  For example a range is 98966-98968, and it correctly ats 98967, but it also adds 98969

Comment: @Brad_J I see your data as `'98966 - 98969'`

Comment: sorry bad example.  In the larger, real dataset there are values such as 99241-99245, 99247.  The output is 99241, 99242, 99243, 99244, 99245, 99246, 99247.  All is correct except 99246 shouldn't be there.  Updated original question with an example

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(split(as.character(df$code), df$name), function(y) {
    unlist(sapply(y, function(x){
        if(grepl("-", x)) {
            n = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "-")))
            n[1]:n[2]
        } else {
            as.numeric(x)
        }
    }, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
})
#$group1
#[1] 93790 98960 98961 98962 98966 98967 98968 98969

#$group2
#[1] 99078
```